# postgresql: how do I dump and restore roles for a cluster?

Tags: postgresql, restore, dump, role

Where are roles stored in a cluster, and how do I dump them?

I did a pg_dump of a db and then loaded it into a different cluster, but I get a lot of these errors:

```
psql:mydump.sql:3621: ERROR:  role "myrole" does not exist
```

So apparently the dump of my db does not include roles.  I tried dumping the 'postgres' db, but I don't see the roles there either.

Do I need to use `pg_dumpall --roles-only` ?

Postgresql versions 8.4.8 and 9.1.4
OS: Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From the [`CREATE ROLE` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createrole.html):

> Note that roles are defined at the database cluster level, and so are valid in all databases in the cluster.

Since `pg_dump` dumps a single database, you can't extract roles with that utility.  The `pg_dumpall --roles-only` command you proposed will do the work - however you may need to filter its output so that only desired roles will be created in the new cluster.

Roles are stored in the `pg_authid` catalog, which is physically stored in the `data/global/` subfolder of a PostgreSQL installation, together with the other cluster-wide tables. You can query the contents of `pg_authid` through the `pg_roles` view.

**NOTE**: you will need superuser rights to dump the roles.  Otherwise, you'd get a permission denied on `SELECT` on `pg_authid` - and even when a superuser grants `SELECT` rights, you'd get the same error.  In this case, however, you can list the roles by querying `pg_authid` directly, `COPY` it to a file and roll some magic to create the necessary `CREATE ROLE` and `ALTER ROLE` statements.

Comment: Can you add how to restore all roles (i.e. no filtering needed)?

Comment: to restore all roles, just copy and paste the output of `pg_dumpall --roles-only` into the desired psql shell. Or specific `CREATE ROLE` and `ALTER ROLE` lines

Comment: any faster way than pg_dumpall --roles-only ? It does not offer any binary output,and any compression :( It is slow especially when loading back via psql